# Retrieving values from MySQL database provide only null values

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, sql

I have created a table  within a MySQL database and need to retrieve the values from it using java but the output only displays NULL values...

Here is my java code..

```
    Connection con;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/electricity", "root", "");
    Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
            active[count] = rs.getString(3);
            reactive[count] = rs.getString(4);
            voltage[count] = rs.getString(5);
            intensity[count] = rs.getString(6);
            meter1[count] = rs.getString(7);
            meter2[count] = rs.getString(8);
            meter3[count] = rs.getString(9);
            price[count] = rs.getString(10);
            count++;
            System.out.println(active[count]+"\t"+reactive[count]+"\t"+voltage[count]+"\t"+intensity[count]+"\t"+meter1[count]+"\t"+meter2[count]+"\t"+meter3[count]+"\t"+price[count]);
    }
```

The output is displayed as below...

```
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null
```

The table has the following attributes...

```
date | time | active_power | reactive_power | voltage | intensity | meter1 | meter2 | meter3 | price
```

I can't seem to find the problem here... I have inserted all data into the table already.

Comment: Have you check what rs.getString(3), rs.getSTring(4)... return? Value or null?

Comment: Also shouldn't you increment count after your println?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you increased your variable "count" before you print value.

try to move count++; to the line after the System.out.println